# Install nuget package to a custom folder

Tags: angularjs, nuget

I have created an ASP.NET 5 app in Visual Studio Community Edition. Then I tried to install the nugget package **angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped** using the command *Install-Package angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped* as well as through the *NuGet Package Manager*. Both these commands dropped the package in the C:\Users\john\.dnx\packages folder.

I changed the **repositoryPath** in the **nuget.config**. Still the packages are saved in the same folders and not under the project.

How can I save the nuget packages under the project and not under *c:\users*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Projects\HelloWorld\src\Scripts"/>
  </config>
</configuration>
```

This is where the packages are dropped.

> C:\Users\john\.dnx\packages\angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped\4.2.8

But I want it under **C:\Projects\HelloWorld\src**

Comment: have you found a workaround for this problem? it seems the definitely typed packages are not working with the latest dnx project template. I also ended with the packages being installed to `c:\users` rather than `src\scripts\typings`

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the not very well documented global.json. This global.json file creates a `packages` sub dir relative to it, where all the nuget packages end up when you restore them.

```
{
    "packages": "packages",
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "runtime": "coreclr",
        "architecture": "x64"
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is this global.json file located?

Comment: Root directory of your application.